# Connect Django to a table owned by a specific user in Oracle Database

Tags: django, python-3.x, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to have my Django connect to an already existing oracle database. This database contains multiple users and tables by each of them. How do I access the tables by a user and where do I need to provide this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate it into Django by inspecting the DB and creating models.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/

You could also:

Use raw queries from Django and handle the results yourself.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Use another database connector as you would in Django-less python.

Comment: Is there a way I can access tables of a particular user

Comment: Database user? Yeah in thebdabases settings in Django.

Comment: I need to access tables of a particular user in the database. How would I go about that. My Django database settings are as below:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
            'NAME': 'name',
            'USER': 'username', 
            'PASSWORD': 'password', 
            'HOST': '.HostName',
            'PORT': '1521',
        }
    }

Comment: Add another database to the DATABASES dictionary DATABASES = {'default': ..., 'legacy':...}

Comment: I don't want a new database. In the same database I wasn't to access tables of a particular user.